# Plot of ideal PDF not close to histogram?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y = e^X$ I have calculated the PDF of $Y$ to be $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{3}{2}\ln(y)}$. But when I plot it against the values I get in practice from a random number generator the curves don't look similar. What am I doing wrong?

Derivation of the PDF:

[It is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815108/is-change-of-variable-formula-for-continuous-variables-just-chain-rule) that if $Y = r(X)$ where $r$ is strictly monotone increasing that $r$ has an inverse $s$ and that:

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(s(y))\frac{ds(y)}{dy}$$

Separately for standard normal distributions we know that:

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$

in this case $s(y) = \ln(y)$

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\ln(y))^2}\frac{1}{y}$$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)\ln(y)}\frac{1}{y}$$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(e^{\ln(y)})^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)}\frac{1}{y}$$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)}\frac{1}{y}$$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)}y^{-1}$$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{3}{2}\ln(y)}$$

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
import matplotlib
import math
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # without this nothing appears?!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys


def pdf_ch2e13(y):
    return (1/math.sqrt(2 * math.pi) * (y**(-3 * math.log(y, math.e) / 2)))

def pdf_ch2e13_hist():
    x = [np.random.normal() for i in range(100000)]
    y = [math.e**i for i in x]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    r = np.linspace(0.0001, 10)
    hist, bins = np.histogram(y, list(r) + [float("inf")], density=True)
    ax2.plot(r, [pdf_ch2e13(x) for x in r], color="red", lw=3)
    ax2.plot(r, list(hist), color="blue", lw=3)
    ax2.set_ylabel('e^(random_normal)')

    plt.show()


pdf_ch2e13_hist()
```

Comment: $Y$ has a [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with a different pdf than what you are getting.

Comment: @StubbornAtom How is it different? If I take their PDF and plug in mean 0 stddev 1 it looks the same to me.

Comment: Your derivation looks faulty. The one you have is not a PDF as can be seen from the fact that is does not integrate to $1$ (integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ of course).

Comment: One should arrive at \begin{align}f_Y(y)&=f_X(\ln y)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\ln y)^2}\frac{1}{y}\mathbf1_{y>0}\end{align}

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I believe the strictly increasing requirement removes the need for the absolute value, and then what I got is a couple algebraic manipulations away from what you have (e and ln cancel to make y the base of the exponent,then you eliminate the division by y by considering it to be $y^{-2/2}$)

Comment: I don't understand the last couple of steps of simplification. It should be $(\ln y)^2$ instead of $\ln (y)^2$ in the first place. No *need* to simply the pdf any further really.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I have updated the derivation to make the steps more explicit. also square of the logarithm is what I was trying to indicate with my notation, I've added parentheses to make that more obvious

Comment: I think the very last step is the mistake.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: you're right, should be $y^{-\frac{1}{2}ln(y) - 1}$. put in an answer and I will mark correct :D

Comment: I would ask you to answer the question yourself by making the correct derivation and accepting the answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom as you wish and thanks

Comment: (+1) for the Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple algebra mistake in the last step of the PDF derivation:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)}y^{-1} \neq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{3}{2}\ln(y)}$$

Instead I should have done:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)}y^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y) - 1}$$

Answer (score 1):

According to [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), the pdf of the lognormal random variable $Y$ (with parameters $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1)$ is
$$f_y(y) = \frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 1 2(\ln(y))^2},$$ 
for $y > 0.$

In the figure below, the solid line uses the lognormal density function
`dlnorm` from R and the heavy dotted line is based on algebraic code
for the expression above. They match.

```
curve(dlnorm(x, 0, 1), 0, 10, ylab="Density", n=10001, xlab="y",
   main="Standard Lognormal Density")
abline(v=0, col="green3"); abline(h=0, col="green3")
curve((1/(x*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-.5*(log(x))^2)), add=T, lwd=3, 
   n=10001, col="blue", lty="dotted")  # 'curve' requires argument 'x'
```

[image]

Starting from that and leaving it to others to correct the errors in draft derivations, we have the following demonstration based
on sampling. (@StubbornAtom has it right.)

We use R to sample a million observations from $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$
find corresponding lognormal values $Y = e^X,$ make a histogram of them,
and plot the lognormal density for comparison. [Because the lognormal
distribution has such a long tail to the right, it is necessary to truncate $Y$-values at $20$ in order to get a useful illustration. (This includes 99.86% of the million observations.)
The lognormal density
is very slightly inflated to account for truncation.]

```
x = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1);  y = exp(x);  yt = y[y <= 20]
hist(yt, prob=T, br=100, col="skyblue2", main="Histogram of Truncated Lognormal Sample")
curve(dlnorm(x)/plnorm(20), add=T, n=10001, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Plenty of people on this site have cleaned up after _my_ typos and blunders. So I'm just trying to pay my dues. The motivation is to leave the page so future visitors won't have to wonder what's exactly correct.

Comment: I see  makes sense